# Restrict property to values defined in other property's object array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Given**

```js
type Props= {
  defaultTab?: string;
  tabs?: {
    id: string;
    // ...
  }[];
};
```

I'd like to update the definition of `defaultTab` to restrict the possible values to those that are contained within `tabs[].id`. For instance, if tabs are supplied by the caller with ids `one`, `two`, and `three`, then the caller should only be able to supply `one`, `two`, or `three` for the `defaultTab` property (or null/undefined, of course).

I as trying to do it like this, but couldn't get there...

```js
defaultTab?: Props['tabs']['id'];
```

But `id` is not defined on `Props['tabs']`, which is true, it's defined on the objects within that array. Not sure how to reference the objects defined within the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible — but it requires a hack.

First, make your `Props` generic. This is needed to establish a relationship between `tabs` and `defaultTab`.

```
type Props<T extends string>= {
  defaultTab?: T;
  tabs?: {
    id: T;
    // ...
  }[];
};

declare class MyComponent<T extends string> extends React.Component<Props<T>> {};
```

We're not done yet. If you do:

```
<MyComponent tabs={[{ id: 'foo' }, { id: 'bar' }]} defaultTab="potato" />
```

it will compile because the allowed values for `defaultTab` will include whatever we pass to `defaultTab`! We need to tell TypeScript that `defaultTab` should depend on whatever we have provided in `tabs`. In other words, we want to tell TypeScript: *first, look at `tabs`. Only then infer what `defaultTab` can be*.

```
/**
 * @see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546
 */
type DeferTypeInference<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

type Props<T extends string>= {
  defaultTab?: DeferTypeInference<T>;
  tabs?: {
    id: T;
    // ...
  }[];
};

declare class MyComponent<T extends string> extends React.Component<Props<T>> {};
```

Now it works!

```
<MyComponent tabs={[{ id: 'foo' }, { id: 'bar' }]} defaultTab="bar" /> // OK
<MyComponent tabs={[{ id: 'foo' }, { id: 'bar' }]} defaultTab="potato" /> // Compile-time error
```

Comment: Darn, almost tried that! Thanks i'll give it a shot.