# How to set type for event.target.value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this Select component:

```
type SelectProps = {
  title: string;
  name: string;
  items: string[];
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
  defValue: string;
};

const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({ title, name, items, onChange, defValue }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>
        {title}:
      </label>
      <select name={name} onChange={onChange} defaultValue={defValue}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <option value={item} key={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </>
  );
};
```

and I'm handling onChange with this function:

```
const onThemeChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
  const theme = e.target.value;
  setTheme(theme)
};

...

<Select
  title='Theme'
  defValue={props.theme}
  name='theme'
  items={['light', 'dark']}
  onChange={onThemeChange}
/>
```

My `setTheme` action creator accepts argument with type `'light' | 'dark'`, so I'm getting an error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"light" | "dark"'
```

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: You can suggest typescript `const theme = e.target.value as "light" | "dark";`

Comment: How is `theme` state defined on your component?

Comment: I'm passing it from redux

Comment: So `setTheme` is an action dispatch from the redux store?

Comment: yes 
`export const setTheme = (theme: 'light' | 'dark'): ActionTypes => {
  return {
    type: SET_THEME,
    theme,
  };
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is away, but it requires a little trick.

First, let's recognize the relationships between types in your `SelectProps`:

- the `items` are string literals
- in `onChange`, the event will have a `target.value` equal to one of your `items`
- the `defValue` should also be one of the `items`

To express these constraints, we need to use a generic interface.

```
type SelectProps<T extends string> = {
  title: string;
  name: string;
  items: T[];
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement> & { target: { value: T }}) => void;
  defValue: DeferTypeInference<T>;
};

const Select = function<T extends string>({ title, name, items, onChange, defValue }: SelectProps<T>) {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>
        {title}:
      </label>
      <select name={name} onChange={onChange} defaultValue={defValue}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <option value={item} key={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </>
  );
};
```

We have achieved everything.

```
<Select
  title='Theme'
  defValue="light" // only "light" or "dark" are accepted
  name='theme'
  items={['light', 'dark']}
  onChange={event => event.target.value} // event.target.value is "light" or "dark"
/>
```

Note the use of a type called `DeferTypeInference<T>`. If you're curious why it's there, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62197877/restrict-property-to-values-defined-in-other-propertys-object-array/62198412#62198412).

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way of doing so would be to do type assertions.

Assuming that this is how you initialised the state,

```
type ThemeState = 'light' | 'dark';

const [theme, useTheme] = useState<ThemeState>('light');
```

And then, on your `onThemeChange` method, you will assert the `value` as `ThemeState`

```
const theme = e.target.value as ThemeState;
```

Comment: I know about this method, but seem like a workaround to me. Is this the proper way?

Comment: @РичардФейнман Not that I know of. But I would recommend you to make the `items` under` SelectProps` to be more type-safe, such that it will not accept any random strings. You can consider changing it to this, `items: ThemeState[];`